# Try to import csv file in google colab from a local machine

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

```py
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
tweets  = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(uploaded['Tweets.csv']).decode('utf-8'), sep = ';')
```

I am trying to import my data but I get the following error:

```
initial_value must be str or None, not bytes
```

Comment: it appears ```uploaded['Tweets.csv']``` holds bytes instead of a string. maybe you need to apply decode on uploaded['Tweets.csv'] ?

Comment: for `io.StringIO` you need string. If you have bytes then maybe you should use `is.ByteIO`

Comment: Thanks..'io.Byte.IO' is work perfectly